# Open sets in a cartesian product

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Suppose you have the following product

$\mathbb{R}^n \times \lbrace 0_{\mathbb{R}^{N-n}} \rbrace$

and another open set $V \subset \mathbb{R^N}$. Is this still an open set if we have the intersection of both sets so to say:

$V \cap \mathbb{R}^n \times \lbrace 0_{\mathbb{R}^{N-n}} \rbrace$.

If we after this take the N-n last entries (equal to 0) of the resulting vectors and cut them of, then we get a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this open?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\mathbb R^n$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^N$ and subspaces inherit properties of  openness.

Don't think of it as intersecting it with the $A \times \{0_{\mathbb R^{N-n}}\}$ first (why *that* set?  Why not any *other* set?)  Just think of it as "cutting off" the last $N-n$ terms from the very beginning.

The end result is this is just a projection of $V$ to $\mathbb R^n$.  It doesn't matter what weird manipulations you did to it along the way.   And projections of open sets into sub-spaces are open.

===== oops ==== misread the question === old answer below ==

No, it is not open unless it is empty.  If $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ then $A \times \{0_{\mathbb R^{N-n}}\}$ is not open.  And any intersection will be of that form.

For any point $p\in A \times \{0_{\mathbb R^{N-n}}\}$ and for any open ball of radius $\epsilon > 0$ centered at $p$ will have points that have non-zero values in the $n+1... N$ "positions".  Thus no open ball of $p$ is completely contained in $A \times \{0_{\mathbb R^{N-n}}\}$.  So no point $p\in A \times \{0_{\mathbb R^{N-n}}\}$ is an interior point.

See [Why is the set $(0,1)\times \{0\}$ not open with respect to $\mathbb{R}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937513/why-is-the-set-0-1-times-0-not-open-with-respect-to-mathbbr2)

Comment: I asked that myself in the context of manifolds and wanted to know whether I might get that set by intersection and by this how openess and other properties are conserved. Would you say it is better from the very beginning to take the open set $V$ and jutst cut of the N-n last entries of the vectors?

Comment: Better? not sure I'd say that. If $V$ is open in $\Bbb R^N$ then $V\cap M$ is open in $M$ if $M$ is viewed as a subspace of $\Bbb R^N$.  So $V\cap\Bbb R^n\times\{0\}$ is open in $\Bbb R^n\times \{0\}$. As $\Bbb R^n\times\{0\}$ is equivalent to $\Bbb R^n$ (so much so that most, texts treat the two as identical), I don't see that this significantly *different* either way of doing it. It's might be worth noting that $\Bbb R^n\times\{0\}$ is not open in $\Bbb R^N$ so when viewed as a subset of $\mathbb R^N$ rather than $\Bbb R^n$ it isn't open, but that's not particularly relevant.

Comment: Ok but as subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is open, that is what I wanted to know. :) Thank you for you answer.